# Chicken or the Egg: Where do I initialize the variable? Detecting single click in XNA

Tags: c#, variables, xna

I have this beautiful cycle of life going here but I need to get it started and being a novice I am not sure where to declare variable currentMouseState as it needs to have a value for this whole thing to work. Working in C# using XNA4.0, thanks :)

```
// mouse management
var lastMouseState = currentMouseState;
// causes error because currentMouseState not declared

var currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
var currentMousePosition = new Point(currentMouseState.X, currentMouseState.Y);

// Recognize a single click of the right mouse button
if (lastMouseState.RightButton == ButtonState.Released && currentMouseState.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    // React to the click
    // feed the fish, someday
    counter++;
    this.Window.Title = "Clicked " + counter.ToString() + " times!";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declared

```
    MouseState currentMouseState;
    MouseState lastMouseState;
```

right before the constructor, and took away the var label on my previous code for these variables. Threw an error saying "the declaration of the local variable hides the field" but it's all good now. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You should put it after currentMouseState.

Answer (score 0):

Defining lastMouseState in the Update-method (Which i assume is what you are doing) does not work.
You have to make it a global variable. (Put it at the top of the class instead of in a method/function)

Since you always want it to store the state of your mouse from the last frame you should always change its value in the end of Update().
If you use it after changing the value it will have the value of the current frame and be exactly equivalent to currentMouseState.